# Login POST request to REST API does not work

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, api, jwt

I am making a post request from the client to the API endpoint. On successful login, API returns a JWT token.

The API perfectly works when sending the request on Postman as illustrated on the picture below:

[image: postman request]

However, when I try to make this request from the client, using AJAX request in order to save the JWT in the local storage on the client, the request does not even appear in the log. So, I assume that something is wrong with my AJAX call.

Here is the client code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#button1').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {email: "test1@reg.ru", password: "123"},
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/login',
                success : function(data){
                    localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
                    alert('ok');
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
        });

</script>

<button id="button1">Test API login</button>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Code shown won't work because the button doesn't exist when the javascript runs. Is that the same order in real page? If so wrap it in `$(function(){ /* code here */})`

Comment: check network calls on developer tools

Comment: you've forgot the `#` sign for your identifier. it needs to be `$('#button1').click(function(e){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@charlietfl correctly pointed out "the button doesn't exist when the javascript runs".

So, when I changed the code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button1').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    email: $('#inputEmail').val(),
                    password: $('#inputPassword').val()
                },
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/login',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

It started to work.

Thanks everybody for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

The selector isn't correct.
Change `$('button1').click` to `$('#button1').click`

Comment: Your function looks correct. Do you get `error` alert after clicking the button?

Comment: No, no errors. Neither in browser nor in node server console.

Comment: I have made a fiddle to test the code https://jsfiddle.net/fn96fp7u/ it does trigger and we get an error alert. Check the console for request parameters.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `dataType: json` attribute in your ajax request, maybe the pattern of return value is not correct so the error callback is executed.

Comment: Thx for the reply. I tried. It didn't help. I use contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" because that is what used in the Postman when it actually works.

Comment: Firstly, `contentType` mains the type of your data that is to be submitted, `dataType` mains the response data type. Is there any way I can test this? Or is there any error occurred during the code execution?